# Error message on post in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have these two action method in my asp.net mvc application:

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        cpd_certificates cpd_certificates = db.Certificate.Find(id);

        return View(cpd_certificates);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Home/Edit/5


   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(cpd_certificates cpd_certificates)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(cpd_certificates).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details");
        }

        return View(cpd_certificates);
    }
```

This is how the paremeters are passed:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {   id=item.CertificateNo  })
```

below is part of my view that calls those two methods above:

```
@model IEnumerable<onlineCPD.Models.cpd_certificates>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        QuizNo
    </th>
    <th>
        Received
    </th>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuizNo)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Received)
    </td>
  <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {   id=item.CertificateNo  })
</td>
}

</table>
```

This is my route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

This is part code for my details method.

```
public ActionResult Details(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, int id)
        {
var certificateDetails = db.Certificate.Where(p => p.ID == id);
 return View(certificateDetails.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Now when I click save, I get this error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], Int32)' in 'onlineCPD.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

I am suppose to pass a parameter in my post, but how do I do this and can someone explain as I just inexperienced here.

Comment: Can you show the code in your view that sets up the form (that is done by the Save button)?

Comment: Can you put it in the main post please, so I can actually read it?

Comment: Okay so you are just using the default route that is fine.

Comment: @MVCKarl Its The Edit says http://localhost:11074/Home/Edit/89376 . This is the same as the save button.

Comment: Your error isn't for the Edit ActionResult, but for details (look close at the error: System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(System.String...)  Are you routing to details using a partial?

Comment: Can you show code of your `Details` action?

Comment: @MarkOreta You are right. Is there a way I can get the value of say QuizNo and pass it on to the Details method which in my question was devoid of a value.

Comment: @testCoder I have include the details method. I need to pass a value indicated there from my Edit method.

Comment: Where do you call your Details method? You need to pass it the id parameter.

Comment: @bardo In the return RedirectToAction. Its in my controller shown above in the code.How do i pass that parameter?

Comment: Try return RedirectToAction("Details/" + yourSortOrderValue + "/" + yourCurrentFilterValue + "/" + yourSearchStringValue + "/" + yourPageValue + "/" + yourIdValue);

Comment: @Bardo thanks for your response. That wont work. i am passing a value other than PK or id.When this value is assed to details it shows a list.

Comment: I supose then your Details method should be able to receive a nullable id (as you maybe don't receive any) so you'll need to define your Details method like this: public ActionResult Details(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, int? id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix `Edit` method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(cpd_certificates cpd_certificates)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(cpd_certificates).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = cpd_certificates.id });
    }

    return View(cpd_certificates);
}
```

In your actionlink do this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {   id=item.QuizNo  })
```

Or alternatively try to change details signature for acceptable nullable value for id, like this:

```
Details(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, int? id)
```

Comment: I see, however its passing the Primary key instead of another value which is in the list of this model. To the method Details I want it to pass say QuizNo which is one of the list item rather than it pass a PK. I am using this in Details to query and show a certain view.

Comment: In what a problem? Pass QuizNo instead of id, or try to add new parameter quizNo and pass number in it, is it that what you seek?

Comment: Yes thats what I seek to pass that quizNo to Details. Not to pass the PK but one of its value in the record.

Comment: You should make `id` parameter of nullable type, it remove any restrictions.

Comment: I have got it. Was suppose to pass this  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {   id=item.QuizNo  }) instead of  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {   id=item.CertificateNo  }). have accepted your answer as well.